# Winform - changing a method to async/await

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, async-await

I have a `winform` with six `listbox` side-by-side.  Under each `listbox` there is a `textbox` and a `Button` labeled "Add."  When you put something in the `textbox`and press the Add button, using EF, I update a table for that `listbox` and I re-`dataBind` the `listbox`.  Here's a sample of one of the event handlers for Add button:

```
private void btnOfferType_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TypeCategoryAdd("OfferType", tbOfferType.Text.Trim());
}
```

`TypeCategoryAdd` function is listed below.  I want to do this (notice the `await`):

```
private async void btnOfferType_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await TypeCategoryAdd("OfferType", tbOfferType.Text.Trim());
}
```

What do I need to do in order make the `TypeCategoryAdd` function to run on different context so that the `winform` UI don't freeze up when DB update is happening?

```
private void TypeCategoryAdd (string table, string item)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(item)) return;

    using (MenuGenerator.NewArchMenuGeneratorEntities con = new NewArchMenuGeneratorEntities())
    {
        switch (table)
        {
            case "OfferType":
                if (con.OfferTypes.Any(x=>x.Name == item))
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("There is already a " + item + " on the list!");
                    tbOfferType.Text = "";
                    return;
                }
                OfferType ot = new OfferType();
                ot.Name = item;
                con.OfferTypes.Add(ot);
                try
                {
                    con.SaveChanges();
                    tbOfferType.Text = "";
                    lstOfferType.DataSource = con.OfferTypes.OrderBy(x=>x.Id).ToList();                    
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Error " + ex.ToString());
                }
                break;                

            }
            return;
        }
```

Comment: Please reduce the code to the [minimum possible to reproduce the error](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @StephenCleary Done. Reduce the code to one `case`.  Thank you for your help, great articles, your blog and your book.

Comment: @StephenCleary Some who had 3K rep points tried to help me but anything that he tried produced some kind of error.  So he decided to delete the whole answer altogether.  So I'm back to square one.  If you have any suggestions on my question I would be thankful.

Comment: The link I posted describes a minimum, complete, verifiable example. That's what you need. As it currently stands, it's not complete (i.e., I can't copy it into a new project and see what you're seeing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you should do it to take advantage of the `async` methods in EF 6:

```
private async Task TypeCategoryAdd (string table, string item)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(item)) return;

    using (MenuGenerator.NewArchMenuGeneratorEntities con = new NewArchMenuGeneratorEntities())
    {
        switch (table)
        {
            case "OfferType":
                if (await con.OfferTypes.AnyAsync(x=>x.Name == item))
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("There is already a " + item + " on the list!");
                    tbOfferType.Text = "";
                    return;
                }
                OfferType ot = new OfferType();
                ot.Name = item;
                con.OfferTypes.Add(ot);
                try
                {
                    await con.SaveChangesAsync();
                    tbOfferType.Text = "";
                    lstOfferType.DataSource = await con.OfferTypes.OrderBy(x=>x.Id).ToListAsync();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Error " + ex.ToString());
                }
                break;                

            }
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm using ADO.Net Entity Frame work.  Sadly it doesn't come with `SaveChangesAsync`

Comment: @Zuzlx [Version 6 does.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn220070%28v=vs.113%29.aspx) If you're using an older version, can't you upgrade?

Comment: It appears I have no choice but to upgrade.  Otherwise, (maybe I'm wrong here) we'll have to wrap things in `Task` so we can return an object that's `awaitable` to the caller.

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap your database access in a `Task`, and `await` on that.

```
private async void btnOfferType_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await Task.Run(()=>TypeCategoryAdd("OfferType", tbOfferType.Text.Trim()));
}
```