# How To Get Value/Variable From URL?

Tags: c#, bitcoin

So I want to write a BTC converter app, I can get the value of it for £1 at https://blockchain.info/tobtc?currency=GBP&value=1
And changing the GBP to USD in the URL changed it to USD naturally, I want to use this and parse the data into a variable and then have it used as a normal. But I want the user to be able to enter their currency and have the url change and then fetch the amounnt in say one canadian dollar. How can I use the GBP as a variable and then have it change depending on user input.
I'm thinking a dropdown box of most popular currencys but I wouldn't know how to use that at all.

Be kind, I'm a noob and trying to make my first useful application

Comment: Still googling it, haven't slept well so genuinely slow today but I need to make a proper application. And need to practice as much as possible.

Comment: Are you asking how to get values from the user, how to construct a url using user supplied data or how to parse the response that you get? Your question needs to be more specific about exactly which part of the problem you are struggling with to avoid us trying to solve problems you are not actually having (and because on Stack Overflow we prefer tightly focussed questions rather than ones that are too broad (and indeed a question can be closed for being too broad).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simply example how you can get the value for the different currencies:

```
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp5
{
    public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(GetValueAsync("GBP").Result);
            Console.WriteLine(GetValueAsync("USD").Result);
            Console.WriteLine(GetValueAsync("RUB").Result);
        }
        public static async Task<string> GetValueAsync(string curr)
        {
            using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
            {
                var responseString = await client.GetStringAsync("https://blockchain.info/tobtc?currency="+curr+"&value=1");
                return responseString;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here

```
client.GetStringAsync("https://blockchain.info/tobtc?currency="+curr+"&value=1");
```

is sending asynchronous http get request by the provided URL and returning response as a string.
The site you want to use is returning just the value as a string that's why this is working.
As the request is asynchronous we must use `await` so that we get response in string.

If you want to do this in WinForm. Here is example. Let's assume that you have already `TextBox` for input value, `Label` for showing result and `Button` for Getting result. They can be added by just drop and down from Toolbox to your form.

```
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp3
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private async void button1_ClickAsync(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string curr = textBox1.Text;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(curr))
            {
                label2.Text = "waiting for response";
                var res = await GetValueAsync(curr);
                label2.Text = res;
            }
        }

        public async Task<string> GetValueAsync(string curr)
        {
            var responseString = string.Empty;
                using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
                {
                    string reqString = "https://blockchain.info/tobtc?currency=" + curr + "&value=1";
                    responseString = await client.GetStringAsync(reqString);
                }

            return responseString;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the full solution for Win Forms [link](http://take.ms/7u4ks)

---

Here are useful links for you:

[MSDN HttpClient GetStringAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh551746(v=vs.118).aspx)
[WinForm with Async Methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37402108/winform-changing-a-method-to-async-await)
[MSDN C# String Concatenation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/strings/how-to-concatenate-multiple-strings)
[MSDN WinForms Click Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.click(v=vs.110).aspx)

---

Here is a recording how to do this also:

[Recording](http://take.ms/EL0QZ)

Comment: Sadly I don't know how to implement that and use it in a form I'll look up about async

Comment: I would urge against concatenating the value into the string like that, rather something like `GetStringAsync($"https://....currency={curr}&value=1");` would be better

Comment: @Ortund there is no difference at all , and also if he doesn't use C# 6.0 or higher string interpolation will not be compiled.

Comment: There is functionally no difference. It does wonders for readability and if he's not using C# 6.0 or higher, `String.Format("http....currency={0}...", curr);` works just fine too

Comment: Think I'm over my head tried the project solution gave me errors, just want to get data from https://blockchain.info/tobtc?currency=GBP&value=1
when the user enter a number and clicks a button it will times the current bitcoin by what the user puts in. Such as £5 or £10 etc

But I don't want the solution only links to how to do it to MSDN etc if possible?

Comment: @LiamVallance I have tested the project stored by the link I have provided it is not giving any errors. Can you send me screenshot of the error

Comment: @LiamVallance I have added some links to the answer, you can look them.

Comment: @LiamVallance also when I was writing the program I have thought that you need to get different value for different currencies. If you need to get value for different amout you can just replace this string `"https://blockchain.info/tobtc?currency=" + curr + "&value=1"` with `"https://blockchain.info/tobtc?currency=GBP&value="+curr` this one

Comment: I cannot use a variable in button in a txt box. This is so confusing

Comment: @LiamVallance I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: Heres my code:
https://paste.ofcode.org/35ArV2AP38ukWyLUPqD45Ux

In "private void txtBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)"
How would you use the variable result to put the result from the url in there. I won't work for me :/

Comment: @LiamVallance When you are adding a `TextBox`  or any other `Control` in WinForm it's getting `Name` you can see it by right-clicking on the TextBox and selecting `Properties`. Then in the code of Form you can do anything with that control by that Name. By default `TextBox`-es are getting name like `textBox1`,`textBox2` and etc. So you can do the following https://paste.ofcode.org/38Cy6Gu3zarv8HGBUPCzCMs

Comment: I'm just not use to how to use controls and pass methods into them, I'll look into your code tho it does show error:
Error CS0029 Cannot implicitly convert type 'double' to 'string'
But changing it to string works, think I may be able to make my app now. Cheers!

Comment: @LiamVallance  replace these lines `var result = Convert.ToDouble(data);
            txtBox1.Text= result;` with `txtBox1.Text =data;`. You don't need to cast the responce to double, because the `txtBox1` needs `string`

Comment: Okay figured that bit out, now I wish to be able to get the data from text box input by the user and times the string variable data by however much (GBP in this  case) so that I can convert BTC easily. I'll add more currencys when I've figured this out, thank you btw for helping a noob!

Comment: @LiamVallance take a look at the recording I have just recorded. I think you will understand how to do what you want. http://take.ms/EL0QZ

Comment: That's exactly what I was wanting to do, thank you for demystifying it!

Comment: Isn't working for me but I'm rewatching it, I must've made a mistake naming a control

Comment: EDIT: Working! Thanks!